# How to Handle Cache Hit Optimization in Multiprocessing Systems

Tags: c, multithreading, caching, multiprocessing

Compiler options providing CPU cache line alignment are considered to achieve more cache hits. But in multi threaded or multi processing systems what guarantees to cache usage of the optimized code will obtain expected cache usage at run time while other processes or threads also use the same cache. In especially, multi core systems provide multiple cpu threads in parallel using cpu cache.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Compilers don't establish the cache line size; that is determined by the architecture. Compilers *may* be instructed to align certain objects on cache line boundaries. That doesn't necessarily result in more cache hits. The term "multiple cpu threads", especially in reference to their use of CPU caches, is ambiguous enough that there's really no way to know what you're getting at there. (Are you asking about hyperthreading for example?) You need to refine your question.

Comment: yes you are right, i have refined some misleading parts in the question. my question is related with the run time. Since caches are shared resources by other processes and cache hits  may also depends to other processes loads. therefore  can we guarantee cache hit optimization level for our code at run time independent from other threads or processes.

Answer (score 0):

Cache line alignment can improve the hit rate because data is less likely to be split between lines, reducing the number of lines whose invalidation could cause a cache miss for that data.  That's true whether it's a single thread or multiple threads sharing the cache.